# excel formula for date status claculation when in non-convertable date format

Tags: excel

We have a date "A2" with format `"YYYY-MM-DD"` and trying to apply the following formula for ETA status determination in B2 cell having the formula

```
=IF(A2="","ETA BLANK",IF(A2<TODAY(),"ETA ELAPSED","ETA UPDATED"))
```

This formula is not giving the intended result for "Elapsed date" since A2 is not in excel understandable date format. appreciate any good way to work around this using change to the excel formula in B2.. please note that we will not be able to add any additional columns and solve this by using the formula in B2

Note: the value in the cell A2 is not converting to a data format unless we do a "text to columns" change date format - but this is not an option in current workflow

Comment: can you change format in the formual directly for example usingthis :

date(left(F14,4),right(left(F14,7),2),right(2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column of yyyy-mm-dd dates and run a text-to-columns on it with fixed width and a YMD date format. Use cell formatting ([Ctrl]+1) to display the real dates any way you want and design your formula on real dates.

Alternately, use [DATEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252)(A2).

```
=IF(A2="","ETA BLANK",IF(DATEVALUE(A2)<TODAY(),"ETA ELAPSED","ETA UPDATED"))
```

The [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252) should recognize text-that-look-like-dates in a *yyyy-mm-dd* format.

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you just use date formatting?

ActiveSheet.Name = Format$(Date, "yyyymmdd")

Some variation of this should work, right?